# Change background color on hover with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Because I am using variable color for buttons, I need to add it with inline css. The hover color is other variable. I cant add hover selector on inline css so, I must use js. I have try to do it with .hover() but when I hover the button both colors desappear.

The code:

```
$('.btn').hover( function() {
    var $hover = $('.btn').attr('data-hover');
    $(this).css( "background", $hover );
}, function() {
    var $color = $('.btn').attr('data-color');
    $(this).css( "background", $color );
});
```

HTML:

```
<button class="btn wpb_btn-small" style="background:#00aff0;" data-color="#00aff0" data-hover="#0cbbfc">Button</button>
```

Comment: you should post the actual HTML and not the PHP

Comment: that is not HTML i've ever seen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.btn').hover( function() {
    var $hover = $(this).attr('data-hover');   // <-- change to this , there are many .btn
    $(this).css({ "background-color" : $hover });  // minor change
}, function() {
    var $color = $(this).attr('data-color');  // same change
    $(this).css({ "background-color" : $color });  // minor change here
});
```

`$('.btn')`  is returning an array - if there are more then one on the page , use `$(this)`

they both should be "background-color"  or "background" , make sure you use the last edit where I made them the same

you could even get really crazy and put it all in one line

```
$(this).css({ "background-color" : $(this).attr('data-hover') });
```

Comment: I just edited a second ago - make sure you get the last edited version - glad I can help , please mark as accepted and upvote if this helped and you find useful

Answer (score 0):

You should use **mouseenter** and **mouseleave** events:

http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

**HTML**

```
 <button class="btn wpb_btn-small" style="background:#00aff0;" data-color="#00aff0" data-hover="#0cbbfc">Button</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $('.btn').mouseenter(function() {
        var bg = $(this).attr('data-hover');
        $(this).css( "background", bg );
    });

    $('.btn').mouseleave(function() {
        var bg = $(this).attr('data-color');
        $(this).css( "background", bg );
    });
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WB8um/1)

UPDATE:
It's actually better using **Hover** event, (refer to the upvoted answer :<)

Comment: why? I actually think the way it is with Hover() and 2 functions looks cleaner